# Adding an Ember Controller causes model to be failed to be loaded

Tags: ember.js

I have the following Route:

```
Inv.InventoryperiodsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/locations/" + location_id +  "/inventory_periods", function(data){
      return data.periods;
    });
  }
});
```

but then when I add an Ember Controller like this:

```
Inv.InventoryperiodsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    saveNewInventoryPeriod: function(){
      alert('about to save');
    }
  }
});
```

The model class fails to load. Just commenting it out brings loading back in and I haven't added anything to the template code. Nothing shows up in the JavaScript console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is still loading, you're just not able to access it. You're extending from `Ember.Controller` directly, which means that your controller with *not* proxy the model, versus the Ember generated controller *does* proxy the model.

As a quick fix, extend from `Ember.ObjectController` instead.

For a more in depth explanation, read the API on the [ObjectProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectProxy.html) class to see exactly what is going on. In general, never extend from `Ember.Controller`, only from `Ember.ObjectController` or `Ember.ArrayController`.